# Thinkorswim to Tradeview

Tags: pine-script, thinkscript

I'm basically looking to port this over but not sure how to.
For one it doesn't pick up the Highest/Lowest references Thinkscript uses

If anyone could help that'd be awesome thanks

```
declare lower;
input perioda = 51;
input periodb = 47;
input RoundingValue = 4;
def llow = Lowest(low, perioda); def c_ln = close - llow;
def hhigh = Highest(high, perioda);
def hn_ln = hhigh - llow;
def numerator = Sum(c_ln, periodb);
def denominator = Sum(hn_ln, perioda);
plot MarketSentiment = round(100* (numerator/denominator), RoundingValue);
marketsentiment.setDefaultColor(color.yellow);
```

Here's what I have but obviously donesn't work

```
study("My Script")
study("idkbro")
perioda = 51, periodb= 47, RoundingValue = 4
llow = Lowest(low, perioda)
hhigh = Highest(high, perioda)
c_ln = close - llow
hn_ln =  hhigh - llow
numerator = Sum(c_ln, periodb)
denominator = Sum(hn_ln, perioda)
plot(MarketSentiment, round(100* (numerator/denominator), RoundingValue))
plot(close)
```

Comment: check the function names in documentation. As far as I see, the functions in your code starts from uppercase letter, whereas, pine used lowercase

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 1):

As @Michel_T pointed out, you should consult [the language documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/) more carefully. The function signatures are different between the two languages. Here're some key points:

1. All functions are lowercase.
2. Your round function with specified precision is not available in Pine. The precision is selected from the settings of the chart instead.
3. You have two "study" functions. You can only have one.
4. The name of the plot title is given as a named argument.

Here's a working code. Note that I use Pine V4.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
perioda = 51, periodb= 47, RoundingValue = 4
llow = lowest(low, perioda)
hhigh = highest(high, perioda)
c_ln = close - llow
hn_ln =  hhigh - llow
numerator = sum(c_ln, periodb)
denominator = sum(hn_ln, perioda)
plot(100* (numerator/denominator), title = "Market Sentiment")
plot(close, color=color.red)
```